# Question about Internships for women at OSRF

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My name is Kalou Katerina, i am  29 years old and currently graduating from
the Msc of Neuroscience at the University of Italy Trento. I am absolutely
interested in programming and that is the path i would like to follow for
continuing my studies.
I just learned about the Internships for Women at OSFR and i would really
like to apply. I am specifically interested for dvelopping the ROS
independent library for system dependency resolution or contributing to the
ROS .ORG visual design
I would like to know if it is to late for me to apply and how exactly i can
make a contribution together with the application for these 2 specific
projects.
Thank you very much for your help
KInd regards,
Kalou Katerina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4970/question-about-internships-for-women-at-osrf/) by [kate12](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/562/kate12/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From Tully Foote's recent message on ros-users:

The Open Source Robotics Foundation is a participating organization in the
latest Outreach Program for Women.

https://wiki.gnome.org/OutreachProgramForWomen/

In an effort to get more women involved in free and open-source
software and robotics, OSRF is offering Outreach Program for Women
internships from December 10, 2013 to March 10, 2014. The application
deadline is November 11, 2013. The applicants need to get in touch
with individual projects they are interested in working on ahead of
the application deadline.

Participants will work remotely from home, while getting guidance from
an assigned mentor and collaborating within their project’s team and
the rest of the community. The projects mainly include software
development but they might be opened to other ideas, such as web
development, 3D modeling, or graphic design. The stipend for the
program is $5,000 (USD). Any woman available for a full time
internship who has not previously participated in the Outreach Program
for Women or Google Summer of Code is welcome to apply.

Below you can find the list of potential ideas for the program.

http://wiki.osrfoundation.org/opw13

Feel free to ask questions and propose suggestions at opw@osrfoundation.org

Please visit http://gnome.org/opw to learn more and apply. This
program is organized by the GNOME Foundation. Please help us spread
the word by forwarding this message to interested university and
community groups.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) with karma: 113 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1